# Firebase hosting. No coinciden mis archivos locales con la version web

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

No entiendo a que se debe la disparidad que tengo entre el volumen y numero de archivos en mi hosting y en mi carpeta local.

Segun Firebase hosting, mi ultima version tendria 719 y ocupa un espacio de mas de 2GB
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo la carpeta que contiene la web en mi sistema local y desde la que hago el firebase deploy, se mucho menor.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay algun modo de cotejar ambas carpetas o de saber que archivos son los que Firebase tiene en el hosting?